# Drupal using rules: User is in organic group logic?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to make a user have a role dependent on a list of values for an organic group using the rules module. I can't use the data comparison field because that only seems to compare exact list values. For example, if I had the numbers 1,2,3,4 in my data compares but I have 1,2,3,4,5 values in my organic group list, I cannot assign the role. None of the other choices I have make sense.

My question is: How do I assign a user to a role in Drupal 7 using the Rules module, based on the value in an organic group list?

Thank you for the help in advanced.

Comment: Can you use "List contains item" in your condition? http://i.imgur.com/V5iSWFE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to create your own rules condition. This is quite simple by using a custom module.

First you have to implement `hook_rules_condition_info`.

```
function mymodule_rules_condition_info() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_og_condition_compare' => array(
      'label' => t('Textual comparison'), 
      'parameter' => array(
        'text1' => array(
          'label' => t('Text 1'),
          'type' => 'text',
        ), 
        'text2' => array(
          'label' => t('Text 2'),
          'type' => 'text',
        ),
      ), 
      'group' => t('Rules'),
    ),
  );
```

Then you must create a custom function, that compares your values and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
function mymodule_og_condition_compare($node, $node_unchanged){
  //Compare values an return TRUE or FALSE
}
```